# "Unfortunately My App has stopped"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, syntax-error

i'was create a app for android but there is a error found " Unfortunately My App has stopped "  so please help me

***AndroidManifest .xml***

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             package="com.example.techtips"
             android:versionCode="1"
             android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.techblogon.activitylifecycleexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".SecondActivity">
    </activity>

    </application>

 </manifest>
```

**Res/layout**

layout2 .xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:textSize="23dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="This Is Second Activity" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

***main.xml***

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView

           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:textSize="23dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="This Is Fist Activity Activity"/>

        <Button
           android:id="@+id/button1"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="      Second Activity     " 
           android:onClick="startSecondActivity"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

src /com.example.techtip/
  ***MainActivity.java***

```
        package com.example.techtips;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Toast;


     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
         /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     @Override

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Create Called In First Activity",                  

    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("FirstActivity", "Inside onCreate");        
    }   

   @Override

  protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Start Called In First Activity",    

   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.i("FirstActivity", "Inside onStart");

   }   

   @Override

    protected void onResume()

 {

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       super.onResume();

    Toast.makeText(this, "On Resume Called In First Activity",   

   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.i("FirstActivity", "Inside onResume");
} 

@Override

protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Pause Called In First Activity", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("FirstActivity", "Inside onPause");
}

 @Override

protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();

    Toast.makeText(this, "On Stop Called In First Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("FirstActivity", "Inside onStop");
}

@Override

protected void onDestroy() 
 {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Destroy Called In First Activity", 

 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("FirstActivity", "Inside onDestroy");

 }
 public void startSecondActivity(View V)
 {
    // create an new Intent and Start Second Activity
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

***SecondActivity.java***

```
  package com.example.techtips;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;


   public class SecondActivity extends Activity
{
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Create Called In Second Activity", 

 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("SecondActivity", "Inside onCreate");

}   

@Override

  protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Start Called In Second Activity", 

   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("SecondActivity", "Inside onStart");
}  

@Override

 protected void onResume()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    Toast.makeText(this, "On Resume Called In Second Activity", 

    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           Log.i("SecondActivity", "Inside onResume");
}  

@Override

  protected void onPause() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Pause Called In Second Activity", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.i("SecondActivity", "Inside onPause");
 }


 @Override

protected void onStop() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();

    Toast.makeText(this, "On Stop Called In Second Activity",  

  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.i("SecondActivity", "Inside onStop");
}

 @Override

 protected void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Destroy Called In Second Activity", 

  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("SecondActivity", "Inside onDestroy");    
   }
 }
```

***Please Help He for Solution***

And also please help me out for create Simple app like this ?? Please Help mE Out

Image : i.stack.imgur.com/20iUi.jpg

Comment: No, no, no, my friend. We need to see logcat to know why it has stopped working. Also, knowing when it stops working would be helpful (on start up, trying to click a button, etc...)

Comment: Agreed, this is far too much information. The Eclipse View "LogCat" will show you the logs for your application. You should see a big block of red text, which is the stack trace (crash log). That information should allow someone to help you.

Comment: I see you are new so a little help. Try to read the logcat and see about where the error is occurring. Post the logcat along with a little explanation of what the app is doing when it crashes. Post code you believe to be relevant to that crash and not code dump. We will kindly ask for more code if we believe it is needed

Comment: And, to find LogCat, go to Window->Show View->Other and search for LogCat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package names in your manifest file dont add up IMO. First try to correct them;

```
package="com.example.techtips"
```

and

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.techblogon.activitylifecycleexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Try changing the second to:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: Awesome Thank yo so much